# Is the Citrus flavored Ciroc vodka kosher?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, liquor-beer

I would like to buy citrus flavored "Ciroc" vodka and wonder if it's kosher?

Comment: It's not listed here http://www.crcweb.org/LiquorList.pdf

Comment: Absolut, Smirnoff, and Svedka are among several of the kosher-certified citrus-flavored vodkas listed http://www.crcweb.org/LiquorList.pdf

Answer (score 9):

Ciroc Vodka is made from French grapes and does not have Kosher supervision.

This is a quote from Ciroc Vodka's website.

> Unlike most other vodkas, which are made from grain, CÎROC®
>   Ultra-Premium Vodka is gluten-free and crafted from fine French
>   grapes, distilled a fifth time at the Distillerie de Chevanceaux in
>   Southern France. These specially selected grapes create the distinctly
>   fresh and smooth taste of CÎROC Vodka.

Comment: Wow, I was expecting a "we don't know if it's kosher." This is actually knowing it's *not* kosher! Cool!

Comment: Amazing answer!  Thank a lot Gershon Gold!!!

Comment: @Shalom It _could_ be that the grapes are only handled by Jews... ;)

Comment: @Daniel Or, more likely, by machines...

Comment: @DoubleAA I once went to a winery that explained that the processing includes "tasting ports" that the "master" uses to check the quality of the wine. This is even when every other step is done solely by machine.

Comment: @sabbahillel That's interesting perhaps but probably not halachically relevant... https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%94_%D7%A7%D7%9B%D7%95_%D7%91 https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%94_%D7%A7%D7%9B%D7%94_%D7%90 https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%94_%D7%A7%D7%9B%D7%93_%D7%9B%D7%93 etc.

Comment: @DoubleAA The citation says שלא בכוונה but the tasting port is designed for the person in charge to take a sample of wine for analysis as well as taste it. Thus it is בכוונה

Comment: @sabbahillel The citations also say ובזמן הזה דהאומות לאו עובדי עבודת כוכבים הם כל מגען מקרי שלא בכוונה plus the Rama in your citation says וי"א דלא אסרינן נצוק בכח עובד כוכבים anyway. Things are not actually as simple as popularly thought.

Comment: @DoubleAA OK however, I would consider it (at least) the same as the maid moving an unsealed bottle of (non-mevushal) wine from the table to the cabinet since he does drink from the wine in the vat.

Comment: @sabbahillel How can you possibly say that after reading the first source I just gave above which explicitly defined your maid case as a Hefsed Mu'at??? In any event, see https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%94_%D7%A7%D7%9B%D7%93_%D7%99%D7%96 about Sichsuch and https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%94_%D7%A7%D7%9B%D7%93_%D7%99%D7%98 about Oseik Bemelachto, both of which add further differences from your maid case.

Comment: @DoubleAA OK I am not an expert in this so I will leave it up to you. I had the impression that the fact that the non-Jew actually drinks from the wine makes a difference.